# The save() function on mongoose doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to save a new doc on mongodb with mongoose but it seems link the .save() line doesn't get executed. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.
This is my code:

```
const rlSync = require('readline-sync');

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/desafio_22012021', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}).then(() => 
  {
    console.log('DB connected');
  }).catch((err) =>{
    console.log(err);
  });

var option;

// model student
const studentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: {
    type: Number,
    require: true
  },
  nameStudent: {
    type: String,
    require: true
  },
  idCourse: {
    type: Array
  }
});
const newStudent = mongoose.model('alunos', studentSchema);

// setTimeout(menu, 1000);

while (option != 0) {
  option = rlSync.question('\nAnswer: ');
  option = parseInt(option, 10);

  switch (option) {
    case 0:
      break;

    case 1:
      console.log('Befora save');
      var documento = new newStudent({_id: 11, nameStudent: "Juliana", idCourse: [1,2]});
      documento.save((err, doc) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        process.exit(0);
      } else {
      console.log('Ok')
      }
      console.log('During save');
      });
      console.log('After save');
      
      break;

    default:
      console.log('Invalid option.');
  };
};
```

This is my CMD:

[image]

When I execute it only the console.logs before and after the function save show up in the CMD. I don't get any error messages either.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems here.

1. `mongoose.connect` is asynchronous and you aren't waiting for the connection before you start your loop. You can fix that by putting the rest of the code in the `.then` callback.
2. `.save` is also asynchronous, but asynchronous code doesn't work as expected in a while loop. The next iteration of the loop started before .save finished executing. One way to handle that is to put the code in a function that calls itself (called a [recursive function](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-recursive-function/))

I've marked the points in comments in the updated code below:

```js
const rlSync = require('readline-sync');

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/desafio_22012021', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}).then(() => 
  {
    ///////////////////////////////
    // #1 Put all this code inside the .then of mongoose.connect so it will wait
    //////////////////////////////
    console.log('DB connected');
    var option;

    // model student
    const studentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
      _id: {
        type: Number,
        require: true
      },
      nameStudent: {
        type: String,
        require: true
      },
      idCourse: {
        type: Array
      }
    });
    const newStudent = mongoose.model('alunos', studentSchema);

    // setTimeout(menu, 1000);

    ///////////////////////////////
    // #2 Recursive function (instead of the while loop)
    //////////////////////////////
    function waitForInput(option) {
      option = rlSync.question('\nAnswer: ');
      option = parseInt(option, 10);

      switch (option) {
        case 0:
          // Not sure what you want to happen here but you can add waitForInput() to wait for input again or put process.exit(0) to stop the program
          break;
        case 1:
          console.log('Befora save');
          var documento = new newStudent({_id: 11, nameStudent: "Juliana", idCourse: [1,2]});
          documento.save((err, doc) => {
              if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                process.exit(0);
              } else {
                console.log('Ok')
              }
              console.log('After save');
              // Function calls itself to wait for next input
              waitForInput()
          });
          break;

        default:
          console.log('Invalid option.');
      };
    }

    // Start waiting for the user input
    waitForInput();

  }).catch((err) =>{
    console.log(err);
  });
```